# Can't install MySQL with error "Transition check error"

Tags: centos, mysql, centos7, mariadb

I'm running on CentOS 7 and at the first MySQL installation it failed, so I shutdown the power (the plug so not properly) and at the second time installation I get the following error:

```
Downloading packages:
mysql-community-server-5.7.21-1.el7.x86_64.rpm             | 164 MB   01:22     
Running transaction check
Running transaction test


Transaction check error:
  file /etc/my.cnf from install of mysql-community-server-5.7.21-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mariadb-libs-1:5.5.56-2.el7.x86_64

Error Summary
-------------
```

(I've paste a bit more for better condition, also there aren't anything under error summary)

I've tried to run commands like `yum remove mariadb-libs` `yum erase mariadb-libs` `yum remove mariadb` `yum remove mariadb-server` `yum clean all` and all can't work

Please help!

Comment: What happens when you run the `yum remove` commands? Any messages?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a little premature but after recreating the issue on my test box I found the following:

I installed mariadb and the after attemption to install mysql-server, I received the same transaction error. I removed mariadb-libs-1:5.5.56-2.el7.x86_64 and the error still occurred. What I did next is:

```
yum remove MariaDB-common*
```

That removed MariaDB-common and MariaDB-client. Afterwards, I was able to install mysql-server with no issues.

Comment: Thank god they don't remove closed questions.